# How to get responses from $.when.apply($, deferreds)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I access the unknown number of responses from a `$.when.apply($, deferreds)`?

Hopefully the below attempt illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
var ajax1 = someAjaxFunction();

deferreds = [ajax1, ajax2, ... ajaxN];
responses = [ajax1Response, ajax2Response, ... ajaxNResponse];

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(deferredsAllDone.apply(responses));
```

I need to be able to access the responses in `deferredsAllDone()`, and I also need to be able to distinguish which response came from which call. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help. You need to iterate the arguments where each argument is an array of `[responseData, statusText, xhrObj]`

```
  var deferreds =[];
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++){
    deferreds.push($.get('data.json'))
  }

  $.when.apply(null, deferreds ).done(function(){
    console.log(arguments)
    for( var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++ ){
      var arg = arguments[i]
      var responseData = arg[0],
          statusText = arg[1],
          xhrObj =arg[2];
    }
  });
```

The arguments of `$.when.apply().done(function() // or then` will be in same order as the original deferreds array.

I believe jQuery 3 has streamlined `$.when` to be more in line with *Promises A+* and to accept and return arrays but I haven't looked into it deeply

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5qydC1vhgwxd6D8SI3r?p=preview)**</kbd>